# Cannot start emulator after installing genymotion

Tags: android, performance, genymotion

I am getting error after i installed genemotion;i am not able to use a normal emulator;
error is;

```
[2014-05-23 20:20:55 - Emulator] invalid command-line parameter: 8.8.4.4.
[2014-05-23 20:20:55 - Emulator] Hint: use '@foo' to launch a virtual device named 'foo'.
[2014-05-23 20:20:55 - Emulator] please use -help for more information
```

So can any one please help me to resolve.

Comment: Can you describe what all steps you've followed while installing Gneymotion ?

Comment: i just followed genemotion setup doc

Comment: Please try to uninstall it and start fresh again. If required reboot the system before doing the same. BTW, "NORMAL EMULATOR" means, gneymotion emulator or Eclipse AVD ? I'm guessing gneymotion's emulator..

Comment: thanks!! unistall everything now its working...

Comment: Please help vote up my comment as it helped you :)